# select fields by using a list in another excel file

Tags: excel, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I work with a CRM to send mailings to contacts. I want to update my unsubscribers so they won't receive any emails anymore.

I cant really make a query of it so I just have a list of people who want to unsubscribe. The list is too big to modify it manually.

Do you guys have any idea how I can approach this problem?

I was thinking exporting the full database to Excel and apply some kind of function where I can select the list I have all at once and change the boolean field (receive emails) to NO.

Answer (score 0):

Export all the desired contacts from CRM to excel, make sure to add the column `Do Not Allow Emails` in view & check the option 'make this data available for re-importing' before export.

Do a `vlookup` with your list & Update the matching contact rows for desired column value in `Do Not Allow Emails` (unsubscribe flag). Save & use this file reimport in CRM to update.

Refer [Export, change & re-import CRM records](https://www.magnetismsolutions.com/blog/paulnieuwelaar/2012/03/19/bulk_update_records_with_export_import_dynamics_crm_2011.aspx)